# anaglyph effect webgl pop out from screen?

Tags: three.js, webgl

i have used anaglypheffect in three.js
[anaglyph effect example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_effects_anaglyph)
and tried to update the shader equation to make the object get out from screen not the depth inside screen , any ideas can help ?

also is this possible wiht any other 3D vision algorithm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Explained in this article [Calculating Stereo Pairs](http://paulbourke.net/stereographics/stereorender/) , i have to change focalLength,eyeSep,eyeSepOnProjection to achieve desired effect manipulating one of these variables changes the depth on 3D vision.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a shader for anaglyph. You simply render the scene twice, once for each eye. For left you only render to red, for right only green and blue. This is easy to do with a color write mask in gl. The 3d effect is controlled by having a different camera matrix for those two passes. By changing them the effect will change. No need to touch the shader. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D

To change the apparent distance of things - behind or past the screen - depends on how you set up the two cameras wrt how two eyes looking at the screen. So if you make the two cameras intersect closer to their origin things will "pop out" more.

Answer (score 2):

In AnaglyphEffect.js the variable `focalLength` represents the distance at which a target will look on the screen plane, and is defined at 125. Further objects will look behind the screen. The eye separation is defined from the focal length as you can see further :

```
var eyeSep = focalLength / 30 * 0.5;
var eyeSepOnProjection = eyeSep * _near / focalLength;
```

The focal length can be added as a parameter in the main function so it can be accessed and modified directly from the main script :

```
THREE.AnaglyphEffect = function ( renderer, focalLength, width, height) {

    ...

    if ( focalLength === undefined ) focalLength = 125;
    this.focalLength = focalLength;

    ...

}
```